# How to call Multiple Website Store in sub folder of main magento installation?

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento

How to call Multiple Website Store in sub folder of main magento installation?

HowMultiple Website Store call in sub folder of main magento installation directoy with same bakend.

Index.php

```
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
/* Store or website code */
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : 'abc';
/* Run store or run website */
$mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'website';
Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
```

.htaccess File is:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/abc/$
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:store]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE} (.+)
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:%1]
```

But then after category URL go to 404 page.

Comment: First, have you reindexed and cleared your caches?

Comment: Second, have you checked that `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` in `core_config_data` is correctly set?

Comment: Yes, Set already, also media and css path set already,
only URL not working design section run successfully

Answer (score 1):

In case if category URL returns 404 page, make sure you reindexed "Catalog URL Rewrites"

Comment: if you get correct store output with 404 page (magento 404 page). it means this category is not in URL Index for some reason. If it is apache (or whatever webserver) 404 page, then there is something wrong with .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is any issue in your .htacess. Please change your .htacess file with new one and then reindex.

Answer (score 0):

So you can remove either the .htaccess or index.php override.

```
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $mageRunCode;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = $mageRunType;
```